# IOS Tableview select row not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to add a checkmark to a selected row and remove it when its selected again, but every time I select a row the checkmark only goes to the first cell and moves downwards after that (ie I click on any cell, then cell 0 has a checkmark, i click on any other cell, cell 1 has a checkmark, etc...).

Here's my didselectrowatindexpath and cellforrowatindexpath methods:

Update:

```
// the cell will be returned to the tableView
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"preflabel"forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"preflabel"];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"preflabel"forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}
```

Comment: Possibly because of reloadData? Reloading the table view clears current state, including the current selection. However, if you explicitly call reloadData, it clears this state and any subsequent direct or indirect call to layoutSubviews does not trigger a reload.

Comment: Don't post your code as an image. Update your question with the actual code (and please format it properly).

Comment: remove `[tableView reloadData]` from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I tried removing the reload data method and now all that happens is the row highlights for a second then unhighlights itself. I also tried removing the deselectrowatindextpath call but now what happenes is that the box is checked and also becomes grayed out, and the text is no longer visible. When I do this I can't unselect the tablebox (which should also be possible)

Comment: @rmaddy I think you meant to say "You shouldn't post code as an image, it causes problems for the moderators. We have an option for adding code which you should use instead." This way you come off as less aggressive and you would make me want to change it to code instead of wanting to upload 10 more images of code just to bug you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [tableView reloadData] this clears the curent state of your tableview.

> Reloading the table view clears current state, including the current selection. However, if you explicitly call reloadData, it clears this state and any subsequent direct or indirect call to layoutSubviews does not trigger a reload.

For more information [see.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/)

**Update**

You are creating tableviewcells in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Why are you doing this? This will write over the cell that was selected.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Comment: Removing it still doesn't add a checkmark to the selected row. The row just highlights for a second then unhighlights and that's the end of it, no checkmark

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

you shouldn't get cell via deque method in the select method, because the cell you get is not the cell you touched,use cellForCellAtIndexPath like the deselect method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```